# How to filter a dataframe using partial matches from another dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, filtering, dataframe

I have two dataframe and I want to use one of the dataframes to filter the other and make a new dataframe. The two dataframes have a column with similar information but it is not an exact match. I have been trying to use `str.contains` but so far I keep getting `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed` when I try. Here is a sample of my dataframes and the code I have tried.

```
promoter = pd.read_csv('promoter_coordinate.csv')
print(promoter.head())

AssociatedGeneName            B      C    D E                                   F
            plexB_1  NC_004353.3  64381  - Drosophila melanogaster (Fruit fly)  region 
               ci_1  NC_004353.3  76925  - Drosophila melanogaster (Fruit fly)  region   
             RS3A_1  NC_004353.3  87829  - Drosophila melanogaster (Fruit fly)  region   
              pan_1  NC_004353.3  89986  + Drosophila melanogaster (Fruit fly)  region  
              pan_2  NC_004353.3  90281  + Drosophila melanogaster (Fruit fly)  region   

data = pd.read_csv('FBgn with gene name.csv')
print(data.head())
Gene AssociatedGeneName   FBgn Number     timepoint
CG10002        fkh        FBgn0000659          2   
CG10002        fkh        FBgn0000659          2   
CG10002        fkh        FBgn0000659          2   
CG10002        fkh        FBgn0000659          2   
CG10006    CG10006        FBgn0036461          2   

x = promoter[promoter['AssociatedGeneName'].str.contains(data['AssociatedGeneName'])]
```

The heads of both list don't have a match but basically the ideal outcome would be something similar to the following, where the two columns that are named 'AssociatedGeneName' would be compared.

```
AssociatedGeneName            B      C    D  E                                    F    
             fkh_1  NT_033777.2  24410805 -  Drosophila melanogaster (Fruit fly)  region
```

Essentially I want a dataframe with all of the values in `promoter` that have a partial match to the values in `data['AssociatedGeneName']` If someone could point me the right direction I would be grateful. I am relatively new to coding, I have been using python and pandas and would prefer to keep using python to solve this problem. Here is the error I keep getting.

```
x = promoter[promoter['AssociatedGeneName'].str.contains(data['AssociatedGeneName'])]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    x = promoter[promoter['AssociatedGeneName'].str.contains(data['Associated Gene Name'])]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py", line 1226, in contains
na=na, regex=regex)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py", line 203, in str_contains
regex = re.compile(pat, flags=flags)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 219, in compile
return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 278, in _compile
return _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 663, in __hash__
    ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: Are there supposed to be duplicate rows in ```data``` ? Or is there exactly  one partial match to every row in ```protmoter``` ?

Comment: yes there are supposed to be duplicate rows.

Comment: Do you want to merge the two dataframes then ?

Comment: No I just want the rows in `promoter` where there is a partial match in `data`. I will try the solution offered and see if it works out for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a function that checks if values from `promoter` has a partial match from `data` this will check for each value in `data`

```
def contain_partial(x , y = data.AssociatedGeneName):
        res = []
        for z in y:
            res.append(z in x)
        return res
```

this will be the result of the function

```
contains = promoter.AssociatedGeneName.apply(contain_partial)
```

then at the end check if at least one value is true then return true and filter 
the `promoter`

```
promoter[contains.apply(any)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.contains` accepts a string as argument and checks if that string is contained within each `promoter.AssociatedGene` entry, then returns `True` or `False` for each index (row).

However, when you pass `data.AssociatedGene` to the `str.contains` function, you are passing a `pandas.Series`, which is why you receive the error.

If you just want the rows where the promoter has a partial match, then you can

```
where_inds_par = [ where(promoter.AssociatedGeneName.str.contains(partial) )[0] for partial in data.AssociatedGeneName  ]
```

Now, each element of the `where_inds_par` is itself a array of indices with length  `>= 0`. Also, there will be some redundancy because your `data.AssociatedGeneName` column is redundant, however you can filter this out using `set`, and some fancy list comprehension

```
inds_par = list(set( i for sublist in where_inds_par for i in sublist )) # set finds the unique elements
promoter_par = promoter.ix[ promoter.index[ inds_par], ]
```