# Using difflib SequenceMatcher ratio to merge in Pandas

Tags: python, merge, fuzzy-search, difflib

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do fuzzy merges of string in Pandas based on the difflib SequenceMatcher ration. Basically, I have two dataframes that look like this:

```
df_a
company    address        merged
Apple     PO Box 3435       1

df_b
company     address
Apple Inc   PO Box 343
```

And I want to merge like this:

```
df_c = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, how = 'left', on = (difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, df_a['company'], df_b['company']).ratio() > .6) and (difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, df_a['address'], df_b['address']).ratio() > .6)
```

There are a few posts that are close to what I'm looking for, but none of them work with what I want to do. 
Any suggestions on how to do this kind of fuzzy merge using difflib?

Comment: might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689147/how-to-filter-a-dataframe-using-partial-matches-from-another-dataframe/31689606#31689606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that might work: test for partial matches for all combinations of column values. If there is a match assign a key to df_b for merging

```
df_a['merge_comp'] = df_a['company'] # we will use these as the merge keys
df_a['merge_addr'] = df_a['address']

for comp_a, addr_a in df_a[['company','address']].values:
    for ixb, (comp_b, addr_b) in enumerate(df_b[['company','address']].values)
        if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,comp_a,comp_b).ratio() > .6:
            df_b.ix[ixb,'merge_comp'] = comp_a # creates a merge key in df_b
        if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,addr_a, addr_b).ratio() > .6:
            df_b.ix[ixb,'merge_addr'] = addr_a # creates a merge key in df_b
```

Now you can merge

```
merged_df = pandas.merge(df_a,df_b,on=['merge_addr','merge_comp'],how='inner')
```