# How to match values from another excel sheet using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been working on an Excel file and looking out to find out accuracy percentage by using Fuzzy match / any other method from another sheet using an dataframe.
Matching other column values using one column having unique values.

**Input values:**

**Sheet 1**

```
identity_no  address            Pincode   company_name

 IN2231      Delhi, Indi        110030    AXN pvt Ltd
 UK654       London, Uk         897653    Aviva Intl Ltd
 SL1432      Colombo, Srilanka  07658     Ship Incorporations
 LK0678      Libya, Sns         5674332   Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd
```

Master Data **Sheet 2**

```
identity_no  address            Pincode   company_name

 IN2231      Delhi, India       110030    AXN pvt Ltd
 UK654       London, Uk         897653    Aviva Intl Ltd
 SL1432      Colombo, Srilanka  07658     Ship Incorporations
```

Looking out to map the column values from Master Data Sheet 2 and update the values into Sheet 1 only when matching accuracy percentage is more than 75% .  based on identity_no.  Also if any identity_no is not present in Sheet 2, We also need to update into sheet 2.

I have tried to use Fuzzy match bot couldn't worked

Script i have been trying to use so far is

```
df = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(open(r'master_data.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet2')

from difflib import SequenceMatcher
lst = df2[['identity_no','address', 'Pincode', 'company_name']]

def closest(s):
    highest = 0
    result = ''
    for i in lst:
        temp = SequenceMatcher(None, s, i).ratio() #Similarity Ratio
        if temp > highest:
            highest = temp
            result = i
    return result
```

How to check for the matching accuracy percentage and only execute the further process when it is more than 75%

```
df[['identity_no','address', 'Pincode', 'company_name']] = df[['identity_no','address', 'Pincode', 'company_name']] .apply(lambda x: closest(x))
```

Comment: Why don't you just merge on `'identity_no', 'Pincode', 'company_name'` and then drop whichever `address` column is less clean?

Comment: @HS-nebula - tried it but didnt worked for me in this case as i have to map from sheet 2 to sheet 1 only when matching percentage is more than 75%.

Comment: You can check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734484/using-difflib-sequencematcher-ratio-to-merge-in-pandas) then.

Comment: I'd also point out that you could do the merge on the three columns, then create a 5th column that contains the ratio between the address columns, and drop rows that are greater than 0.75 - might be easier than fuzzy merging